# What is a generator for this ideal?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra, prime-numbers

According to the Hilbert Basis theorem, there is  a finite number of  generators for the ideal $I$ in $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$ generated by $\{(x^{n}+y^{n})\mid n\in \mathbb{N})\}$. What is the precise  least natural number  $N$  such that $\{(x^{n}+y^{n})\mid 1\leq n \leq N\}$ generate the  above ideal?

I  have the same  question by replacing the above $I$  with the ideal generated by $$\{(x^{p}+y^{p})\mid p\;\; \text{is a  prime}\}$$

Answer (score 2):

The *Newton-Girard* relations between elementary symmetric functions and sums of powers show this ideal is generated by $x+y$ and $xy$. This may be generated to more than two indeterminates.

Comment: what is  Newton-Girard relations?

Answer (score 1):

A basis for $I$ is $[y^2, x+y]$, which is generated by $x+y$ and $x^2 + y^2$
(since $y^2 = (x^2 + y^2 - (x+y)(x-y))/2$).

Comment: what about $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ instead of $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$?

Answer (score 1):

It's enough to take $N= 2$. In fact, if $J = (x+y,x^2+y^2)$, then $xy\in J$ because $2xy = (x+y)^2 - (x^2+y^2)$.

Then proceed by induction to show that $x^n + y^n \in J$: it's clear by definition for $n=1,2$. Now $n\geqslant 3$: $(x+y)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{} \binom{n}{k}(xy)^k(x^{n-2k}+y^{n-2k})$ (check that).

Since $(x+y)^n$, $(xy)^k$ and $x^{n-2k}+y^{n-2k}$ are in $J$, it follows that $x^n + y^n\in J$.